# What am I doing wrong in my SQL query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm setting up a post-purchase journey where consumers will receive an email after purchasing certain items from certain collections.

On my first try, I managed to gather this data, however the issue was that it kept retrieving the data from any purchase throughout their whole purchase history instead of the most recent one (last 24h).

The pilot started with only 3 of our collections.

This the the SQL query with sample data:

```sql
select
t2.SubscriberKey,
t2.Basket_Id,
t2.ProductGroup,
t2.Subtotal_Value
from (
  select
  t.SubscriberKey,
  t.Basket_Id,
  t.ProductGroup,
  sum(t.Subtotal_Value) as Subtotal_Value,
  row_number() over(partition by t.Basket_Id order by sum(t.Subtotal_Value) desc) as rn
  from (
    Select
    p.SubscriberKey,
    p.Basket_Id,
    p.Product_Name__c,
    CASE
      WHEN p.Product_Name__c like 'Name %' THEN 'FullCollectionName'
      WHEN p.Product_Name__c like 'Name%' THEN 'FullCollectionName'
      WHEN p.Product_Name__c like 'Name%' THEN 'FullCollectionName'
      ELSE 'Others'
    END AS ProductGroup,
    p.Amount__c*p.Product_Value as Subtotal_Value
    From ENT.Brand_Purchases p
    Where p.CreatedDate > dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())
    AND p.Product_Name__c IS NOT NULL
  ) t
  group by t.SubscriberKey, t.Basket_Id, t.ProductGroup
) t2
where t2.rn = 1
```

What did I achieve with this SQL so far that I wanted to achieve?

- I gathered all products within the basket and if one of those products with the highest purchase value belongs to any of the 3 collections selected for the pilot, it will show the collection name instead of "Other"
- It gather now the most recent purchase (last 24h)

What is still wrong?

- Various records that should have gone to "FullCollectionName" wen to "Other". Meaning that the SUM of the total purchased products from that collection within the same basket were higher than the products labelled as Other, but it still went to Other
- Some SUM of the products are wrong. Sometimes it shows 0 or less than the actual sum of the products purchase from the same collection

Any tips from SQL Query experts?

Comment: I'd recommend running your innermost query first and then moving outward when you get what you expect.

Comment: I'd also probably add another sub-query for the sum, before ranking the rows with row_number().

Comment: thank you, Adam! I'll give it a try and make these changes.